# Duplicate an already installed app in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Somebody knows how can I duplicate an already installed app in Odoo like "maintenace" for example?
I tried to duplicate the folder inside the addons path with a different name but it's not working.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Odoo module is stored in the table ir.module.module.

It's possible to duplicate the Odoo module. But, you need to change the folder name of the module with another name (for example: maintenance). Because on the base Odoo module with class ir.module.module, Odoo generate the XML ID record using `'module_%s' % YOUR_FOLDER_NAME.`

This is why you don`t see your duplicated module.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but you'll have to [update your apps list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Note that the 2 modules will still be managing the same data unless the model names are changed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).